What is the role of the components in this AC coupling circuit?
I'd like to learn more about the RP2040 PWM Audio AC coupling circuit found in figure 22 in this document & shown below.

Even though I understand the general purpose of AC coupling, can someone clarify the specific role for each of the components placed after the logic buffers output in the circuit? (It appears to me that the circuit is duplicated for each of the stereo channels, so I'm referring to R1, C7, R3, C14 and R7).

These are bandpass filters. And yes, the two circuits are identical as each one filters one channel of a two-channel stereo pair.
In this case, R1 (R2) and C7 (C8) form the low-pass part of the filtering. The low-pass filter's job is to attenuate the higher frequencies; i.e. the PWM modulation.
R3 (R4), C14 (C15) and R7 (R8) form the high-pass filter(s). The high-pass filter's job is to attenuate the lower frequencies contained in the signal that is passed to it from the low-pass filter.
That may sound counter-productive, but both the high-pass and low-pass filters have a pass-band and a cutoff frequency (the 3 dB point). By properly designing the filters, the designer can select a range of frequencies that fall within the pass-band of both filters. In this case - for an audio signal - the pass-band should contain the audible frequencies.
The figure below illustrates how the high-pass and low-pass filters combine to create a band-pass filter:
fL < Pass-Band < fH

Using this portion of the Wikipedia page, you can test your hearing against the audible range. This will (may) show you that your ears also act as low-pass filters to attenuate the higher audio frequencies! This will allow you to make reasonable judgments on just how much you should spend on your next stereo system  :)
